# Packages from running integration module are not excluded

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I´m running some integration test from module A getting first all the classes from module B, what I´m interested is in not add in the coverture some packages from B, but also some package from A.

I´m using excludes in the jacocco plugin, and all the packages that I´m specify from B are exlude perfectly, but the ones from A it dont

Here my config

```
  <plugin> 
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId> 
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version> 
                <executions> 
                    <execution> 
                        <id>prepare-jacoco-service-test-agent</id> 
                        <!-- default pre-integration is to late for the process-exec-maven-plugin --> 
                        <phase>package</phase> 
                        <goals> 
                            <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal> 
                        </goals> 
                        <configuration> 
                            <propertyName>failsafe.argLine</propertyName> 
                            <includes> 
                                <include>com.in*</include> 
                            </includes> 
                            <excludes> 
                                <exclude>com.B.dg.*</exclude> 
                                <exclude>com.B.es.core.server.vertx.*</exclude> 
                                <!--f2e-core-test--> 
                                <exclude>com.B.es.client.service.*</exclude> 
                                <exclude>com.B.es.core.service.test.*</exclude> 
                                <exclude>com.B.es.core.test.helper.*</exclude> 
                                <exclude>com.B.es.coretest.*</exclude> 
                                <!--f2e-mock--> 
                                <exclude>com.A.f2e.*</exclude> 
                            </excludes> 
                            <classDumpDir>${project.build.outputDirectory}</classDumpDir> 
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile> 
                            <append>true</append> 
                        </configuration> 
                    </execution> 

                    <execution> 
                        <id>report-jacoco-service-test-results</id> 
                        <goals> 
                            <goal>report-integration</goal> 
                        </goals> 
                        <phase>verify</phase> 
                        <configuration> 
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile> 
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/out/</outputDirectory> 
                        </configuration> 
                    </execution> 
                </executions> 
            </plugin>
```

Any idea why any package of module A it´s not excluded?

Answer (score 1):

By configuring `exclusions` for `prepare-agent-integration` you specified that packages should be excluded from instrumentation, but not from report. You need to configure `exclusions` for `report-integration` instead.

Comment: I try to put in there also, but nothing, still add the sources in the report folder coverage-reports/out/. All regarding jacoco it´s a mess, or maybe muy use case it´s bizzar

Comment: @paul In this case please provide **complete** and **verifiable** example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your difficulties - partial excerpt of a `pom.xml` is clearly not enough to reproduce and understand your issue.